# how to display date and time in tomcat catalina.out log file

Tags: tomcat7

I need to display the date and time of actual log info within the `catalina.out` log file for my tomcat7 installation.  From the web I found the solution of adding this line to the `logging.properties` file, but it does not work.  I added the following:

```
1catalina.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS,%1$tL
```

Right now its just a bunch of data that has zero timestamps.  I just want the standard `yyyymmdd hhmmss` that precedes the **INFO** or **ERROR**, etc. in the log output.

what is present right now in my `logging.properties` file is this (I added the last line obviously):

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
1catalina.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS,%1$tL
```

The version I'm using is `apache-tomcat-7.0.82`.

Any help you can provide would be great, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on Tomcat 7.0.99:

```
...
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8

# My special format:
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tF %1$tT [%4$-7s] %5$s %n
...
```

The first three lines are out of the box default settings. Just the last line defines SimpleFormatter. Logfile looks like this:

```
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0]. 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true]. 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019] 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["http-apr-8080"] 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["ajp-apr-8009"] 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] Initialization processed in 368 ms 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] Starting service [Catalina] 
2020-02-03 11:55:26 [INFORMATION] Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.99
```

For more information regarding SimpleFormatter see: [Oracle Java Documentation - SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) and for Formatter see: [Oracle Java Documentation - Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

You can even change Tomcat logging to log4j (see: [Tomcat - Using_Log4j](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j)) but that needs some more effort and would be an overkill for my simple use case.